# SQL Server 2014 Service Pack (SP3-CU4-GDR - KB4583462) install faliure

Tags: sql-server

I ran into an error during the install of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4-GDR) (KB4583462) - 12.0.6433.1

During the script upgrades to the system database the upgrade ran into:

This is from the SQL error log:

> 2022-05-22 02:22:52.35 spid11s     Error: 515, Severity: 16, State: 2.
> 2022-05-22 02:22:52.35 spid11s     Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'packagedata', table 'msdb.dbo.sysssispackages'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>
> 2022-05-22 02:22:52.35 spid11s     Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.
> 2022-05-22 02:22:52.35 spid11s     Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 515, state 2, severity 16. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.
> 2022-05-22 02:22:52.35 spid11s     Error: 3417, Severity: 21, State: 3.
> 2022-05-22 02:22:52.35 spid11s     Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> 2022-05-22 02:22:52.35 spid11s     SQL Server shutdown has been initiated

Comment: Can I suggest that you upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server as 2014 has been out of mainstream support for a few years already

Answer (score -3):

I was able to fix this by praying and then:
Alter the table 'msdb.dbo.sysssispackages' to allow column 'packagedata' to allow null values.

In my case here this error was on a clustered database server, so I failed back to the node that was not upgraded yet and was able to alter the table.

If this had been a stand along server, I could have copied the msdb database file and log file to test server and attached it to get it mounted and made the changes. Then it would be as simple as to detach the database and copying it back to the original server, then try the startup/upgrade again.

Next time I upgrade a sql 2014 instance to (SP3-CU4-GDR - KB4583462) - 12.0.6433.1, I will likely alter this table a head of the upgrade.

Comment: Unlikely that is what you are supposed to be doing. Most likely the reason there is a null value is because it's corrupted, so there is a row which has a null. Best option in this situation is to restore `master` from a backup, then run `DBCC CHECKDB` to correct errors if any

Comment: Altering system tables to change the schema isn't supported & could result in unexpected behavior in the future.